# mapping values to d3.voronoi in p5.js

Tags: d3.js, processing, p5.js

i've been working with p5.js for a while, but i just picked up d3/p5 to make some voronoi diagrams. I have an existing program where an array of 512 points are mapped to the screen. I want to use those points to make a voronoi diagram.

the only relevant reference i can find is http://codepen.io/sepans/pen/Qbgaby

however, this program operates solely within function setup(), as it is a static program. this is the beginning:

```javascript
function setup() {


  var width = 1500,
    height = 1000;


  // randomly generate vertices in [[123,57],[43,67], ..] format

  var vertices = d3.range(100).map(function(d) {
    return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height];
  });

  // using d3.js voronoi layout to calculate voronoi polygons

  var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .clipExtent([
      [0, 0],
      [width, height]
    ]);
```

I unsure how to move these elements into function draw(), so that my continuously dynamic variables can feed into the diagram.

this is probably not 100% clear so if anyone has any advice as to how i can explain my problem more effectively that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want continuously dynamic variables to feed into the diagram? Where are these variables coming from? Do you understand what the `var vertices = ` line is doing?

Comment: i am not sure what the 'var vertices = ' line is doing / how it works. 

this program takes data from p5.AudioIn and assigns coordinates to 512 frequency data points based on their respective amplitudes. therefore, this process runs through 'function draw()' and each frame reassigns coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this program is this line:

```
var vertices = d3.range(100).map(function(d) {
  return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height];
});
```

Please try to understand what this code is doing. It's filling the `vertices` array with 100 random points.

You say you want to fill your diagram with points you gather from somewhere else. You need to get rid of this line and populate `vertices` with your points. The best advice I can give you is to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time.

For example, get this working with just a couple hard-coded points. Then try to add points when you click the mouse. Don't worry about your final end goal yet, just get these simple examples working. Then if you get stuck, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific question. Good luck.

Comment: At some point I thought that would be the case. within `function draw()` I have this:

`for (x = 0; x < 512; x ++) {
 xC = log(x / q)*sin(2*pi*x / q);
 yC = log(x / q)*cos(2*pi*x / q);
 vX[x] = xC;
 vY[x] = yC;
     point(xC, yC); }`

where `q` is an updating value based on the audio input. My difficulty is with populating `vertices` with `vX` and `vY` — I'm not sure the syntax for doing so.

Comment: @ASwedler Like I said you should really be working in a smaller example. Get rid of all of that logic and just try to add a hard-coded point. Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on JavaScript objects available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-objects).

Comment: thank you for that referral. i will post a more simplified version, but just to follow up, if i wanted an array of coordinates like `vertices = { [4.2, 3.5], [1.1, 5.2], [2.7, 2.9], ... }` would i create an array of object literals? I haven't fully wrapped my head around how objects worked, so i have avoided them in the past.

Comment: @ASwedler I think you have your `{ }` curly brackets and `[ ]` square brackets mixed up, but in general that's one way to create an object.